# Transition from Upper Bound definition for Sets to Sequences using Logical transitions & Set-Builder notation

Tags: logic, proof-writing

Upper bound definition for sets: $ M \in \mathbb{R} $ is an upper bound of set $ A $  if $ \forall \alpha\in A. \alpha \leq M$
Upper bound definition for sequences: $ M \in \mathbb{R} $ is an upper bound of sequence $ (a_n)$  if $ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}. a_n \leq M$
Suppose we look at the set $ A = \{ a_n | n \in \mathbb{N} \} $ .

I've been pondering for a while about the following 2 questions related to mathematical-writing , logic and set builder notation:

**Questions:**
**1.** How do we get with logic from the defintion of upper bound for sets to the definition of the upper bound for sequences using the set $ A = \{ a_n | n \in \mathbb{N} \} $? My reasoning:
$ \forall \alpha \in A . \alpha \leq M  \iff \forall \alpha.( \alpha\in A \rightarrow \alpha \leq M )  \iff  $ $\forall \alpha.( \alpha \in A \rightarrow \exists n \in \mathbb{N}. \alpha = a_n \rightarrow \alpha \leq M ) \iff $   $ \forall \alpha.( \alpha \in A \rightarrow \exists n \in \mathbb{N}. \alpha = a_n \rightarrow \alpha \leq M \rightarrow a_n \leq M) $ Hence $ \forall \alpha \in A \exists n \in \mathbb{N}.( \alpha=a_n \land a_n\leq M $ ), Now this is not equivalent to the defintion of upper bound of sequences above ( $ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}. a_n \leq M$  ), why? can you please give correct transitions? I've made mistakes but It's confusing me to see how to write them correctly.

**2.** Someone told me that since every element of $ A = \{ a_n | n \in \mathbb{N} \}  $ is generated by every element of $ n \in \mathbb{N} $ so therefore $ \forall \alpha\in A. \alpha \leq M$ is equivalent to $ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}. a_n \leq M$ .
How is that possible that the two statements are equivalent? Since for arbitrary $ \alpha \in C $ there exists a specific $ n \in N $ ( not arbitrary ) therefore it appears false to write $ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}. a_n \leq M$ but seems more reasonable to write $ \exists n \in \mathbb{N}. a_n \leq M$ .

Comment: Does it help to think of the sequence as a function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $A$? The elements of $\mathbb{N}$ behave like names for the elements of the set $A$. The same thing can be known by many different names. $A$ might have only one element. In $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ you go through all the names; in $\forall \alpha \in A$ you go through the elements themselves.

Comment: Intuitively yes, but I want to know how to make the transitions using logic. The transitions are:  
$ \forall \,\alpha \in A\, : \, \alpha \leq M\in \mathbb{R} \Longleftrightarrow \forall\,\alpha(n)\in A\, : \, \alpha \leq M\Longleftrightarrow \forall \,n\in \mathbb{N} \, : \, a_n \leq M $  
where $ \alpha(n)= a_n\in A $ is parameterized/labeled by $ n $.   However, I don't know why we have $ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}. a_n \leq M $ instead of  $ \exists n \in \mathbb{N}. a_n \leq M$ Since for all $ \alpha \in A $  there exists specific $ n \in \mathbb{N}$ and is not arbitrary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In part the question asks why $\forall \alpha \in A : P(\alpha)$ is logically equivalent to $\forall n \in \mathbb{N} : Q(n)$ where:

- $A = \{a_n \in \mathbb{R} : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$,
- $P(x)$ is some property of real numbers, and
- $Q(n)$ is the property of natural numbers defined by $Q(n)$ holds iff $P(a_n)$ holds.

Start by supposing $\forall \alpha \in A : P(\alpha)$. We need to justify $\forall n \in \mathbb{N} : Q(n)$. To do that, pick an arbitrary $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and consider the element
$a_n \in A$. We have that $P(a_n)$ holds, so by definition of $Q$, also
$Q(n)$ holds. Our choice of $n$ was arbitrary, hence $\forall n \in \mathbb{N} : Q(n)$ as required.

This shows
$$\forall \alpha \in A : P(\alpha) \Rightarrow \forall n \in \mathbb{N} : Q(n).$$

We still have to justify the converse implication. Suppose that
$\forall n \in \mathbb{N} : Q(n)$. Pick an arbitrary $\alpha \in A$.
For this $\alpha$ there must exist some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$\alpha = a_n$. Of course there may be many such $n$, but all that matters is that we can find at least one. We know that $Q(n)$ holds for this particular $n$ because it holds for all of them. By the definition of $Q$, this means that
$P(a_n)$ holds. Hence $P(\alpha)$ holds as $\alpha = a_n$. Since $\alpha$ was arbitrary, we conclude $\forall \alpha \in A : P(\alpha)$.

This shows
$$\forall \alpha \in A : P(\alpha) \Leftarrow \forall n \in \mathbb{N} : Q(n).$$

In predicate logic the rule that allows you to deduce $\forall x: P(x)$ when you have established $P(x)$ for an arbitrary $x$ is called generalization. Expressing the whole argument formally and symbolically is entirely possible though might make it less clear.

Comment: So for the following example , the iff is true?: $ \forall \alpha \in \{ x| \exists n \in \mathbb{N} \exists q \in \mathbb{Q}. P(x(n,q)) \} \iff \forall n \in \mathbb{N} \forall q \in \mathbb{Q}. P(n,q) $ , where $ P(n,q) $ is a property that holds for q and p , and P(x(n,q)) is a property that holds for x that depends on $n$ and $q$

Comment: That does not quite make sense. Logic involves a lot of being very fussy with details, and $P(n,q)$ has two arguments but $P(x(n,q))$ has only one. Also in the first expression $x$ appears twice and there is no very clear connection between them. I will edit the answer to bring in what I guess is the issue: that $P(a_n)$ feels like it needs to be more obviously a property of $n$.

Comment: That's better, also I meant for example:  
Denote $ B = \{ x| \exists n \in \mathbb{N} \exists q \in \mathbb{Q}. x=q+n \} $.  Then the following holds 
 $ \forall \alpha \in B  \iff \forall n \in \mathbb{N} \forall q \in \mathbb{Q}. q+n \in B $   
How do I denote the properties though in this case? for example I to want write properties $ P  $ and $ T$ such that  
$ \forall \alpha \in B. P  \iff \forall n \in \mathbb{N} \forall q \in \mathbb{Q}. T $ 
However, what do they depend on? ( It seems like P depends only on $ \alpha $ whilst T depends only on $ n $ and $ q $ )

Comment: It is usually good to make things as simple as possible at first. You could try $B=\{x : \exists n \in \mathbb{N} . x = 2n\}$ so it's easy to imagine the set $B$. Maybe you can write your example using the property of being an even natural number. Does it help to think about $\forall x \in B: even(x) \Leftrightarrow \forall n \in \mathbb{N}: even(2n)$?

Comment: I understand that example. But In any case I'll ever encounter a little more difficult set such as $ B = \{ x| \exists n \in \mathbb{N} \exists q \in \mathbb{Q}. x=q+n \} $. How for example would one write properties $ P , T $ for an 'iff' transition such as $ \forall \alpha \in B. P  \iff \forall n \in \mathbb{N} \forall q \in \mathbb{Q}. T $ ? The difficulty here lies in the questions: does $ P $ depend on one variable? and does $ T $ depend on two variables? If both are true, is it logically correct?

Comment: Define $B=\{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid \exists n_1, n_2 \in \mathbb{N}. x = f(n_1, n_2)\}$ for some function $f$. Suppose property $P$ can apply to real numbers, and define $Q(n_1, n_2)$ to be $P(f(n_1, n_2))$. Then $\forall x \in B . P(x) \Leftrightarrow \forall n_1, n_2 \in \mathbb{N} . Q(n_1, n_2)$. Here $Q$ depends on two things and $P$ on only one.